# Jetty fails to start with ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient

Tags: websocket, jetty

I'm trying to create a war file containing single WebSocket servlet. For some reason jetty wants HttpClient, even though I'd like to have only server side logic. HttpClient is there in the "jetty-client-9.4.0.v20161208.jar" file under Jetty. But that's not listed in the status dump (jetty.server.dumpAfterStart=true).

web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>WebSocketApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.test.MyJettyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Socket:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/control")
public class ControlSocket {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("WebSocket opened: " + session.getId());
    }
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String txt, Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Message received: " + txt);
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(txt.toUpperCase());
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(CloseReason reason, Session session) {
        System.out.println("Closing a WebSocket due to " + reason.getReasonPhrase());

    }
}
```

Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.2'

    compile group: 'javax.websocket', name: 'javax.websocket-api', version: '1.1'

    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.16'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.21'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'  
}
```

I'd assume something wrong with dependencies. But what exactly? Should I include websocket implementation jars? If yes, then why?

Answer (score 3):

If you using jetty-distribution, add the `client` module.

```java
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=client
```

This is being improved in Jetty 9.4.1 btw.

Comment: That unfortunately does not work:
C:\Servers\jetty-distribution-9.4.0.v20161208\carj-test>java -jar ../start.jar --add-to-start=cli
ERROR : Unknown module='cli'. List available with --list-modules

Comment: The answer says "client", not "cli"